# Angular: display an icon instead of a text

Tags: angular, typescript

Let's say I have a component.ts like this:

```
@Input() studentHeader?: BaseStudent;

 get studentText() {
        if(this.studentHeader) {
            return this.studentHeader.nr + ' - ' +
                this.studentHeader.firstname + ' ' +
                this.studentHeader.lastname + ' ' +
                this.studentHeader.gender + ' ' +
        }

        return '';
    }

        get iconStudent() {
            let icon = null;
            if (this.studentHeader) {
                switch (this.studentHeader) {
                        case (this.studentHeader.gender === 'FEMALE') :
                            icon = 'icon_female_i.svg';
                            break;
                        case (this.studentHeader.gender === 'MALE') :
                            icon = 'icon_male_i.svg';
                            break;
            }
            return icon;
        }
}
```

and I have a HTML template like this:

```
<div class="h-header">
    <div class="h-header-left">
        <div class="iconStudent"></div>
        {{studentText}}<br>
    </div>
```

After compiling this, it leads to the following:

1 - John Doe MALE

, thus only the text appears and not the respective icon. But how is it possible to display the icon instead?

Comment: How did you display your icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work!

```
    <div class="h-header-left">
        <img [src]="iconStudent" />
        {{studentText}}<br>
    </div>
```

Comment: @Marc - also ensure that your path to the icon is correct. example: if its in the assets folder then inside an icons folder, the correct path would be 'assets/icons/icon_female_i.svg'

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div class="iconStudent"><img [src]="iconStudent" /></div>
```